# Необязательные параметры в хранимых процедурах MySQL

Tags: mysql, procedure

Как я могу задать необязательные параметры для хранимой процедуры mysql? Или же указать значения параметров по умолчанию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по ответам на англоязычном форуме, [это все еще невозможно](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982798/is-it-possible-to-have-a-default-parameter-for-a-mysql-stored-procedure), поскольку mysql все еще не поддерживает опциональные параметры. Все параметры придется передавать явно. Но при этом "зубры" указывают лазейку - передачу NULL как значение параметра и проверку на NULL внутри SP. Сам с необходимостью необязательных параметров еще не сталкивался, но со времени последнего ответа на этот вопрос синтаксис `CREATE PROCEDURE` не менялся, все еще только `IN / OUT / INOUT` в параметрах, и никаких дефолтных значений.